# Linking in debug symbols

Tags: gcc, linker, cygwin, debug-symbols

I am building thrift 0.2.0 on Windows 7 under Cygwin. All compilation options say "-g -O2" and the compiled object files contain debug symbols. However, the final executable is missing them, as confirmed by both gdb and nm. There are no error messages, warnings, or suspicious flags in the output. There is no "-s" among link flags. What could be happening? How do I even diagnose it?

Comment: Is there an intermediate linker step that is building a library? If so, that might be where the --strip-debug is happening.

Comment: It seems like a fairly straitforward single-step link: $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CXX $(AM_LIBTOOLFLAGS) $(LIBTOOLFLAGS) --mode=link $(CXXLD) $(thrift_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(thrift_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(thrift_OBJECTS) $(thrift_LDADD) $(LIBS)

Comment: I am generally comfortable with the Unix environment, but I don't use it for work, so I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, *libtool* was the problem. Running the same command without it built the program with symbols.